# Swift adding button dynamically to UIScrollView but its not scrollable why?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to dynamically add buttons in UIScollView so that it becomes scrollable when the buttons overflow than its size but its not happening.

```
for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
    let magButton=UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: Int(newScroll.frame.origin.x), y: verti, width: Int(newScroll.frame.width), height: 25))
    magButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(imageTapped), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    magButton.backgroundColor=UIColor.gray
    magButton.tag=count
    magButton.contentMode = .left
    magButton.setTitle(data.value(forKey: "name") as! String, for: UIControlState.normal)

    myScrollVew.addSubview(magButton)

    verti+=26
}
```

Comment: Where do you update the scroll view's `contentSize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add last line which update the scroll view content size.

```
myScrollVew.addSubview(magButton)

verti+=26
myScrollVew.contentSize = CGSize(width: myScrollVew.contentSize.width, height: magButton.frame.maxY)
```